# Python config parser array sort according to file content sequence

Tags: python, arrays, readfile

I'm reading a config file from python.

file contents to be read:

```
[environment]
env = openstack

[nodes]
appserver-mgr2
appserver-wkr2
```

I'm reading nodes section as follows.

```
def load_server_config():
        config = ConfigParser.RawConfigParser(allow_no_value=True)
        serverList = []
        config.read('deployment.cfg')
        dic = dict(config.items('nodes'))
        for node, ip in dic.iteritems():
                serverList.append(node)
        print serverList
        return serverList
```

When I print the serverList array, it is not in the order I have put in my file.
It is printed as follows.

```
['appserver-wkr2', 'appserver-mgr2']
```

I have to manually sort the array in ascending order.

```
serverList.sort()
print serverList
```

Then the output becomes.

```
['appserver-mgr2', 'appserver-wkr2']
```

But I want to extract nodes section in to an array in the same order that I have put in my file which is to be read.

Say for an example my file content is as follows.

```
[nodes]
appserver-p
appserver-q
appserver-a
appserver-b
```

I want to construct array content as follows.

```
['appserver-p', 'appserver-q', 'appserver-a', 'appserver-b']
```

How can I do that?

Comment: dict are not ordered. Check orderedDict (https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per @fredtantini I used orderedDict as follows.

```
import collections
def load_server_config():
        serverList = []
        config.read('deployment.cfg')
        orderedDic = collections.OrderedDict(config.items('nodes'))
        for node, ip in orderedDic.iteritems():
                serverList.append(node)
        print serverList
        return serverList
```

File contents.

```
[nodes]
appserver-mgr2
appserver-wkr2
appserver-wkr3
appserver-wkr4
```

I got the results I needed.

```
['appserver-mgr2', 'appserver-wkr2', 'appserver-wkr3', 'appserver-wkr4']
```